# How to execute the same expect simultaneously for multiple hosts after spawn

Tags: parallel-processing, background-process, expect, spawn, simultaneous

I am trying to ssh to multiple hosts at the same time and execute the same commands simultaneously for all. I am using expect to log in and send the commands automatically. The script that i created bellow works but connects and executes the commands serially for each host one after the other. What I want is to put the expect to work simultaneously for all the hosts like creating a child process for each host or working in the background.

Any ideas how to reach that?

For my code I am reading a file that includes multiple IP addresses and pass it to the script.

Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/expect
set prompt ">"
set fd [open ./hosts r]
set hosts [read -nonewline $fd]
close $fd

foreach host [split $hosts "\n" ] {
        set timeout 30
        spawn ssh admin@$host
        lappend spawn_id_list $spawn_id
}
foreach id $spawn_id_list {
        set spawn_id $id
                while (1) {
                        expect {
                                "ssh:" {
                                        exit
                                }
                                "no)? " {
                                        send "yes\r"
                                }
                                "password: " {
                                        send "password\r"
                                }
                                "$prompt" {
                                        send "some commands\r"
                                        break
                                }
                                timeout {
                                        exit
                                }
                                -re . {
                                        exp_continue
                                }
                                eof {
                                        exit
                                }
                        }
                }

}

expect eof
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using Expect's `fork`?

According to Expect's [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

> `fork` creates a new process.  The new process is an exact copy of  the
>   current  Expect  process.  On success, `fork` returns `0` to the new
>   (child) process and returns the process ID of the child  process
>   to  the  parent  process.  On failure (invariably due to lack of
>   resources, e.g., swap space, memory), `fork`  returns  `-1`  to  the
>   parent process, and no child process is created.
>
> Forked processes exit via the `exit` command, just like the original process.  Forked processes are allowed to write to  the  log
>   files.   If  you  do not disable debugging or logging in most of
>   the processes, the result can be confusing.
>
> Some pty implementations may be confused by multiple readers and
>   writers,  even  momentarily.   Thus, **it is safest to fork before
>   spawning processes.**